# Adjusting Header Height Using jQuery

Tags: jquery, wordpress, header, height

I'm attempting to use jQuery to shrink the height of my header when a top menu item is clicked and sub-menu opened. So far it works well, but I'd like to implement some additional code that checks whether the header has already been shrunk before it runs the animation again i.e. if you've already selected a menu item and want to switch to view another sub-menu, I don't want the header to animate again.

Any help would be greatly appreciated - this is for a Wordpress site using Ubermenu.

Thank you!

```
var $w_banner = $('.ls-wp-container, .ls-slide');
var w_banner_height = $w_banner.outerHeight(false);

    $('.ubermenu-item-level-0').on('ubermenuopen', function(evt) {
        $w_banner.animate({ height: "175px" }) ;
    }).on('ubermenuclose', function(evt) {
        $w_banner.animate({ height: $w_banner.data('height') + "px" }).css('max-height', $w_banner.data('height'));
    });

$w_banner.data('height', w_banner_height).css('max-height', w_banner_height); // Store initial height
```

Comment: Could you please add a sample of your HTML to the question. It's also a little odd to attach your event handlers in a `setTimeout()` call. Is this an attempted workaround for having the elements dynamically added to the DOM?

Comment: What's the set timeout for?

Comment: I'd forgotten I'd left the timeout in there, it's not needed at all, I'll remove it.

Comment: What you have should work fine, although you may need to use `stop(true)` if you want to end the current animation before starting a new one

Comment: Thanks Rory - it does work fine, but what I'm keen to replicate is the functionality you can see on this website: http://camstar.industrysoftware.automation.siemens.com/

i.e. when you click on 'Site Explorer' the header shrinks and if you then click on 'Contact' it remains 'shrunk'. Whereas on my site if you were to switch between the two, the header would return to it's default height and then shrink back when the other link is clicked.

I just wondered whether there was a mechanism to stop it doing this using the code above?